# Drawing pixels from buffer and position (glDrawPixels)

Tags: c, opengl, gldrawpixels

Basically I am doing some tests to simulate various window inside a scene. Everything works fine until I try to position better the window that I am drawing inside the scene.

The important code is here:

```
// camFront = glReadPixels ...

glMatrixMode( GL_MODELVIEW );
glLoadIdentity();
//glRasterPos3f(1.0, 0.5, 0.0);  // <-- commented out

// Zooming window
glPixelZoom(0.5, 0.5);      

glDrawPixels(500, 250, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, camFront);  //> camFront is the buffer of the window
glutSwapBuffers();
```

Basically when `glRasterPos3f` is commented out I got my nice window drawn inside my scene:

[image]

Now If i try to position that window with `glRasterPos3f`, the window disappears completly from the scene... Any clues?

Comment: is the new position possibly culled? this would cause said symptoms

Comment: @user3125280: I am trying many different values for glRaster.. even glRaster(0,0,0) hides that window =/

Comment: glRasterPos3f(1.0, 0.5, 0.0, 1.0); is the last coordinate not a divisor in 3 argument call? EDIT: no, in three argument call third argument is z, not w

Comment: Do you mean glRasterPos3f(1.0, 0.5, 1.0);  (3 inputs)? Anyway tried, it does not appear. (doesn't compile with 4 arguments)

Comment: @link: Do you really need to use `glDrawPixels()` at all. Beside the fact that it is deprecated, it has also always been a very ineffcicent path. To me, this looks more like you want different to viewports and/or render-to-texture.

Comment: glRasterPos3f(1.0, 0.5, 0.0, -1.0); ? it appears the new coordinate (once transformed) is not valid, and so is "clipped' like a normal vertex. see if you can draw a point or something at those coordinates

Comment: Well I don't explicitly need DrawPixels, but now performance aren't a prolbem. I simply don't get how to position a window with DrawPixels. EDIT: why do you keep writing RasterPos with 4 arguments... it doesn't compile...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>One possible</strike> The cause of this problem is an invalid rasterpos. The raster pos is set after transforming x,y and z just like any other pixel. This includes the clipping stage.

The easy test is to see if when a bright point (or something more visible) is drawn at your x,y and z it appears on the screen.

**Where is (1.0, 0.5, 0.0) in your screen? Is it visible?**

The coordinate has to be a visible point that is projected onto screen, becoming a 2d coordinate. Try putting the code before the modelview part, maybe then the coordinate will be where you expected.

Because you reset the matrix with glLoadIdentity, the point (1.0, 0.5, 0.0) will be at the right edge of screen - possibly clipped as too far right or too close to camera.

```
GLboolean valid;
glGetBooleanv(GL_CURRENT_RASTER_POSITION_VALID, &valid);
if(valid == GL_FALSE) 
    printf("Error");
```

(The second test is better than drawing something, but won't help tell you where it is being drawn if it is not invalid)

Comment: do you mean I need to use void `glGetBooleanv` ? It doesn't compile your code (also please note I am using C)

Comment: Ok I tried your code. When I use glRaster (with whatever values) I got the error. When I comment out glRaster I don't get the error

Comment: noted - error is a placeholder for your error handling code - just printf("Invalid Raster Position\"); or something

Comment: @llnk the x,y and z must be a visible point in your scene -  try (0.5,0.5,0.5)

Comment: Hm yes that's the problem. But at this point how can I know which glRaster position can I use ? (tried with .5, .5, .5 - not working)

Comment: @llnk maybe (0.0, 0.0, 3.0) or something in the center - how do you set the veiwport? (i think?)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44101/discussion-between-user3125280-and-llnk)